# How can the same code in two Firebase Cloud Functions, which only differ in its trigger, yield different results?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have two functions: one that triggers every Sunday at midnight UTC and another that is called through an https request. They both have the same logic inside, literally copy pasted (except the https CF, which has to respond to the client):

```js
export const weeklyChallengeManagerFunction = functions.pubsub
    .schedule('every sun 00:00')
    .timeZone('Etc/GMT') // UTC
    .onRun(async () => {
        try {
            const resetProgress: UserChallenge = new UserChallenge()
            const challengeProgress: any = resetProgress.toFlatObject()

            const update = {
                challengeProgress,
            }
            await updateAllUsersInBatches(update)
            return
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
        }
    })

export const testWeeklyChallengeReset = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const resetProgress: UserChallenge = new UserChallenge()
        const challengeProgress: any = resetProgress.toFlatObject()

        const update = {
            challengeProgress,
        }
        await updateAllUsersInBatches(update)
        res.json({ ok: true })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        res.json({ ok: true, err })
    }
})
```

These functions are supposed to reset the `challengeProgress` field of all the Firestore Documents in the `users` collection to its default values, which are defined in the default values of the UserChallenge class constructor.

`updateAllUsersInBatches` is defined like this:

```js
const updateAllUsersInBatches = async (update: any) => {
    const db = admin.firestore()

    const query = await db.collection('users').get()
    let batch = db.batch()

    query.docs.forEach(async (userSnap, index) => {
        if (index !== 0 && index % 500 === 0) {
            await batch.commit()
            batch = db.batch()
        }
        batch.update(userSnap.ref, update)
    })

    await batch.commit()
}
```

Lastly, the pubsub scheduled has no records of timeout due to cold starting or any error of any kind. Only two logs are registered: the "function started" log and the "function ended ok" record.

This morning there was a user document that had not been reset by the pubsub function(the only active user btw, as this is not in production), but I copy-pasted the exact same logic in an https CF, deployed, executed and it worked.

My question is: **How is that possible? What am I missing?** There are no errors in stackdriver either.

NOTE: `toFlatObject(): any` is a function that returns the object instance as a plain object instead of a class instance. It is part of an interface defined by me as IFlatable as a workaround to the fact that firestore can't receive class instances and save them to firestore directly. They have to, somehow, be "flattened" to plain javascript objects:

```js
toFlatObject(): any {
    return Object.assign({}, this)
}
```

Comment: Are the triggered function and the http request running with the same security principal?

Comment: @Turo I don't exactly understand what you mean by "security principal", but if you mean security rules then yes, they are running with the same security principles. These two functions are part of the same Firebase project. They are even written in the same file.

Comment: Do you have the timestamp of when the user was created. Because, if the pubsub execution is on Sunday and you test it the following Tuesday, changes may naturally occur from your user base.

Comment: Sorry, I have no timestamp. But there are no active users in this app because it is still in its development process. The only "active user" is a person of the team doing QA. That's why I found it weird that both functions don't do exactly the same :) @Juancki what I mean is that changes could not occur because of natural use of the app by any user base

Comment: Are you sure that the pubsub or http is only executed once. If you execute this function in parallel with different update values, the result is indeterminate due to a race condition.

Comment: Yes, but I'll look into the possibility of there being a race condition. Maybe some batch is failing to update, and the users in that batch stay inconsistent.